# Problem using two 74HC595 to create a 16-bit output

Tags: shift-register, 74hc595, bascom

I'm migrating a code made in Bascom from a fully functional hardware to a C language (XC8)
Through two 74HC595. They increase to 16 digital outputs.

[image]

The way they do it is like this

[image]

I have made my code, but it doesn't work, that is, I send some value to either of the two 74HC595s, but their outputs are always at logical zero.

So I turned to the logic analyzer to see what's going on, and apparently the time diagram is fine.

In the following image I send 0x80 to the first 74HC595, and 0x03 to the other.

[image]

I suspect that perhaps between both bytes (0x80 and 0x03) there must perhaps be a pause or something, but I can't find what the timing diagram of two or more 74HC595s connected in cascade looks like.

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You don't need to pause. Even the first device is not working so you have something else wrong. What speed are you clocking at - the units on your logic analyzer output is unreadable?

Comment: @KevinWhite: The major ticks are "9,600 ms" apart, which I'm assuming wold be 9.6 ms to us Americans. So about 500 bps.

Comment: Probably double check the wiring and signal voltage levels to make sure they are correct

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks for answering. The period of the clock signal has a duration of approximately 2 ms

Comment: What are those last two traces on the logic analyser?

Comment: @FabiánRomo - that is extremely slow so that is not a problem. Check your wiring. That should work. When you get it working don't forget that the first data you shift in ends up in the second register after being shifted completely through the first. Also you don't have to dynamically use the reset signal - any new data will push out existing data.

Comment: How much delay is there between changing the DATA line and setting the SCK high? Are you sure you're meeting the setup time?

Comment: @FabiánRomo [Here's how it looks in simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fug6N.png), handled manually (me poking buttons by hand.) Latches fine. Your logic diagram doesn't show voltages. Is it possible that your signals are meeting the requirements of the analyzer's full-featured input but aren't meeting the HC requirements?

Comment: Are you sure the data values are what you expect? First value sent out, 0x80, would go to last chip, and it does not have anything on that bit. The last value sent would go to first chip in chain at MCU, and 0x03 would turn only one bit on, as 0x01 is again unused bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to all those who responded.

I have carefully checked the hardware and discovered cold solders on the 74HC595s.

So I re-soldered and cleaned them, and at first the outputs started to activate, not in logical order, but after reviewing my code, there was a small error, but I managed it.